# How do you add a UIView over a TableView-iOS

Tags: c++, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm developing an RSS reader app and i'm trying to make the app have only 2 views (the tableview and the webview) I don't know how to add a UIView over my tableview.

Comment: You really need to give us more information.  What have you tried so far?  How did you add the UITableView?  Have you tried doing the same thing with your UIWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, I am not able to understand your question, hoping that one can be your solution.

**1.** Solution one, show the stuff on the same Page

[image]

a. For this in your interface builder file,drag a UIWebView and add it as subView to a View.
Keep this webview top aligned.

b. Now drag a UITableView and add it as subview to a UIView at say y=150 and keep this tableview bottom aligned.

c. Start making connections to interface file to your code files. To do first you need to declare  it in your .h the header file as listed below.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *feedsURLArray;
}
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *feedsTableView;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *feedsWebView;
@end
```

After declaring it go to you interface builder file. Now right click on you tableView , you will see datasource and delegate , point them to your viewController. Along with it make feedsTableView by connecting it as "Referencing Outlets".

Also connect feedsWebView as "Referencing Outlets".

d. After we are done with the connections, we can start writing up the code. Lets initialise  the table with urls and on click of a UITableViewCell we make a NSURLRequest on UIWebView Object. This will be written in your .m file.

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize feedsTableView,feedsWebView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    feedsURLArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [feedsURLArray addObject:@"https://www.facebook.com"];
    [feedsURLArray addObject:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    [feedsURLArray addObject:@"http://www.google.com"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark Table Methods
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return feedsURLArray.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[feedsURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *urlStr=[feedsURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.feedsWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]]];
}

@end
```

**2.** Second solution would be you can add your UIViewController to a UINavigationController. This UIViewController will only display the feeds url and its relevant details.

You need to then create another UIViewController which will have only a UIWebView, which will be pushed on UINavigationController when UITableViewCell is selected.

**3.** Third Solution would be to create a customCell. This cell will have a UIWebView as one of the subview.

For this Initially you can keep the height of the cell as 44.0, but as soon as this cell is selected, you can increase the height to say 200 , so that your UIWebView is visible.  Call loadRequest on UIWebView when tap occurs.

**Things to know** when you use UIWwebView in you application you will have to handle navigation (back and forward) by your own. A thought on it would be to open the ios Default browser using the following code.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *urlStr=[feedsURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
}
```

or else refer this site for [Demo on creating a browser](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/21/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-1/) which handles navigation back and forth just like iOS default browser.